# Scapy sniff() doesn't seem to capture TCP packets, only shows ethernet frames

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy

I have tcpdump and scapy running `sniff()` on the same interface. There is a scp file transfer happening.

tcpdump: I see the tcp packets with the seq and acks going over.

scapy `sniff()` returned list: All I see in each packet summary() is `(MAC addr1 ) > (Mac addr 2)  (0x800) / Raw`. Even in the packet `.show()`, all I see is a link layer stuff with "## [ Ethernet ] ##", src and dst.

I ran this with a timeout of 30 so I know I would capture the scp transfer of an empty text file so I know I timed it right.

There are definitely TCP packets going over, but none of them are being detected. Is there an issue with Scapy?

Thank you

Comment: TCP is encapsulated in IP, which is encapsulated in ethernet. The IP packets are the payload of the ethernet frames, and the TCP segments are the payload of the IP packets. You simply are not decoding deep enough.

Comment: Please report the output of `sniff()` and of a `pkt.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a bug that prevents Scapy from processing the ethernet payload.

You can try to set `conf.debug_dissector = True` to debug the issue.

You can also get the current development version of Scapy (from the [repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)), since this may be an already fixed bug (we had a bug similar to what you are seeing with Python 3 until very recently).

If the bug still exists after updating to the current development version, please [report it](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new)!

Comment: I fixed it. You were right. I just needed to update to the latest version because my version was buggy. I deleted an old comment here because I also fixed that too.